# KendiUI ListView Delete button with Alert

Tags: kendo-ui

I have got a list view and I have added a Delete button to it. But its not presenting me with a Delete confirm dailog box. Do we need to specify any setting for it?

Here is the html for edit button in the template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at here : the doc : http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/listview#events-remove

Here is an extract :

```
$("#listView").kendoListView({
    template: "<div>#: name#</div>",
    dataSource: {
        data: [
            { id: 1, name: "Jane Doe", age: 47 },
            { id: 2, name: "John Doe", age: 50 }
        ],
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "id",
                fields: {
                    id: { type: "number" },
                    name: { type: "string" },
                    age: { type: "number" }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    remove: function(e) {
        //handle event           <---  LOOK HERE
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Just add in remove function a code like what you want :

```
        var response = confirm('Are you crazy ?');
        if (response== false ) { }
```